Alternative to bang (!) and system()
I'm hoping someone with real Vim insight can help me with this. I am using the MSWin32-64 build of Gvim on a Windows 10 laptop. I have Cygwin installed. I can start Gvim from a Cygwin bash shell and Gvim inherits the environment of bash, most notably,$PATH. I'm explaining this because I am hoping to avoid annoying comments like "WHY DO YOU WANT TO DO THAT". Now I will explain the problem.
The ! at the Gvim commandline opens a new terminal and the shell ($SHELL, &shell) executes whatever is on the commandline after bang !. In the _vimrc, I let &shell=bash and let $SHELL=/full/path/to/shell.
Well, this works fine if the cwd of Gvim is the same as the directory of the current buffer (%). But if not, Vim passes % as ..\parent\subdir\buffer.bla. And there is no way around it that I can find. I can change the direction of the slashes:
:echom substitute(@% ,"\\", "/", "g")
but bang ignores that. It does no interpolation whatsoever. Well, then there's system(). It would allow me to interpolate an argument, e.g. result = system(substitute(@% ,"\", "/", "g")) but I want to see all output, error messages, etc in a new terminal, and system doesn't do a terminal (iow it runs a new process in the background and returns what the stdout of the program was).
That's all.

Not entirely off-topic here, but you might get better results from vim.stackexchange.com

NOTE: this is fundamentally the same as the existing answer but more usable in a day-to-day context.
You can use :help filename-modifiers to, well… modify the filename right there in the command-line. Here is how it looks, using cat as an example external command:
:!cat %:gs?\?/?:S

where:

:gs?\?/? substitutes every backslash with a slash,
:S escapes special characters.

Adding :p to make the path a full path might be useful as well:
:!cat %:p:gs?\?/?:S


:execute '!<your_command> ' . shellescape(substitute(@% ,"\\", "/", "g"))

Construct a cleaned up filename, create a command including ! as a string and run the string using execute.
